# offset background color outside border with css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an responsive container (Wordpress with visual composer) with a background color and border. If I want the background a little outside the container. (like a offset print error) How to achive this. I have dabbled with background-position. But can't get it to work in WP and dosn't seem to work with negative?

[Background and border offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Cek.png)

Comment: Please provide an image with the desired outcome. Will help us understand your question better.

Comment: outline, box-shadow, background-clip can be used alone or together to draw fancy borders, can you clarify your question and share enough code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Im not allowed to post inline image. So its a link.. sorry

Answer (score 4):

You could replace `border` with `outline`, and use a negative `outline-offset` value.

[*Note that this is not supported by Internet Explorer](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=outline)

```css
div {
  background: black;
  outline: 5px solid yellow;
  outline-offset: -10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```